# Creating a sine function with specific parameters

Tags: trigonometry

**Part1(Solved)**

Is it possible to create a function that maps x to y as follows:

x 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 ...

y 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1  0  1  2  3  4  5 ...

So far, this is what I have been able to come up with:

|5 sin ((1/10)*pi*x)|

Which will give the following y's for x = 0 to 10:

```
 0.00000
 1.5451
 2.9389
 4.0451
 4.7553
 5.0000
 4.7553
 4.0451
 2.9389
 1.5451
 0.00000
```

This sequence will repeat every 10 steps, with the peak (5) at step 5. This is getting close to what I want so all that is left is to somehow adjust the function so that the required integers appear (1,2,3,4), but I don't know how.

Since the function is cycling through a series of numbers over and over, I figured that it might be possible to write the function in terms of a periodic function and not piece by piece.

Please comment.

**Part2**

How would I go about writing a function that produce the following plot:(x is an integer >=0 , the pattern repeats after x = 8)

[image]

Can this plot be expressed using a single formula or must it be defined piecewise?
  Thank you.

Comment: A piecewise linear function will do of course. Are there any extra requirements, like smoothness for example?

Comment: Youre example of $|5\sin(\pi x/10)|$ doesn't actually work.

Comment: You probably should have asked "part 2" as a separate question...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$\frac{5}{\pi}\arccos\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{5}\right)\right)$ seems to do what you want, unless you need something smoother.

Comment: ...and this is in fact the "natural" piecewise linear function passing through the given points, but written in a clever way.

Comment: I should say @Hans, I thought of it immediately after I saw your comment. :)

Comment: @J.M: How did you find that function? Very impressive. http://i.imgur.com/JdBQf.jpg

Comment: @JM: Yes,that is exactly what I wanted. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Two considerations @Robert: 1.) $\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{L}x\right)$ has period $L$, and 2.) the range of $\arccos$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is $[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score 3):

You ask for a function. A function is a mapping from one set to
another set, but you neglect to specify which sets. Your list of
$x$-values consists of small nonnegative integers together with
an ellipsis. From this, one might surmise that your intended
domain is $\mathbb{N}_0$, the set of nonnegative integers. Likewise
you do not specify a codomain, but let's say for argument's sake
that it is $\mathbb{N}_0$, the same as the domain.

Of course there are uncountably many functions from $\mathbb{N}_0$
to $\mathbb{N}_0$ containing your specified values. But you mention
it has to be a "sine" function. The term sine refers to a particular
function on the real numbers, taking all values between $-1$ and $1$
and having period $2\pi$. Your function cannot have all of these
properties. Perhaps by a "sine" function you mean a periodic function?
If so here is one defined on $\mathbb{N}_0$ which extends your table
of values:
$$f(n)=\begin{cases}
0&\text{if }n\equiv 0 \pmod {10},\\\\
1&\text{if }n\equiv\pm1 \pmod {10},\\\\
2&\text{if }n\equiv\pm2 \pmod {10},\\\\
3&\text{if }n\equiv\pm3 \pmod {10},\\\\
4&\text{if }n\equiv\pm4 \pmod {10},\\\\
5&\text{if }n\equiv 5 \pmod {10}.
\end{cases}$$
Of course, unlike the actual sine function, this never takes negative
values.

Perhaps as in Hans's comment, you want a function on the reals
restricting to your table of values. Here is a piecewise linear
example as Hans suggests:
$$g(x)=
\begin{cases}
10\{x/10\}&\textrm{if }\{x/10\} < 1/2,\\
10-10\{x/10\}&\textrm{if }\{x/10\}\ge 1/2
\end{cases}$$
where $\{t\}$ denotes the fractional part of a real number $t$.

Answer (score 0):

**PART 1** You were close: Look at your values. They rise with slope $1$ till $5$, and then continue with slope $-1$. This may be described by the function
$h(x)'=\text{sgn}(\sin(\pi x/5))\,$.

$\hskip1.7in$[image]

(from [W|A](http://tinyurl.com/7j3axsu)).

Integrate this, $h(n)=\int_0^n \text{sgn}(\sin(x))\,dx\,$, and you're done.

Instead of that, you might adapt the Fourier Series for the [Triangle Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave#Harmonics) to your problem:
$$
\begin{align} x_\mathrm{triangle}(t) & {} = \frac {8}{\pi^2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \, \frac{ \sin \left( (2k+1)\omega t \right)}{(2k+1)^2} \\ & {} = \frac{8}{\pi^2} \left( \sin (\omega t)-{1 \over 9} \sin (3\omega t)+{1 \over 25} \sin (5\omega t) - \cdots \right) \end{align} 
$$

**Part 2** Starting from $(n,h(n))=(9,5)$, you have $6$ values decreases, followed by a jump of $+3$ and then $6$ values increasing. So this is essentially the same problem with an additional offset function $\frac32 \left(\text{sgn}(\sin(\pi x/5))+1\right)$...